# Logical error in this query?

Tags: sparql

I have two `where` clauses.

```
PREFIX tourister: <PREFIX_VALUE> 
SELECT ?a 
WHERE { 
   {?a tourister:hasRating ?b .
     ?b ?c '5'@string } . 
   {?a tourister:hasFeature ?b . 
     ?b ?c 'Pool'@string }
}
```

They work fine, when executed on their own, or if there is a `UNION` clause between them, however, I am looking for Intersection. From what I have read online, I came to find out, that '**`.`**' can be used for intersection. However, with the `.`, I get 0 results. No, Syntax Error, something wrong with the Logic.

And, please note, the `PREFIX_VALUE` in the above query is not an error, I have omitted it intentionally.

```html
<!-- http://tourister.space/ontologies/tourism#TESTInd -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://tourister.space/ontologies/tourism#TESTInd">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://tourister.space/ontologies/tourism#Hotel"/>
        <hasFeature rdf:resource="http://tourister.space/ontologies/tourism#TESTIndFeature"/>
        <hasRating rdf:resource="http://tourister.space/ontologies/tourism#TESTIndRating"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://tourister.space/ontologies/tourism#TESTIndFeature -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://tourister.space/ontologies/tourism#TESTIndFeature">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://tourister.space/ontologies/tourism#Feature"/>
        <hasName xml:lang="string">Pool</hasName>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://tourister.space/ontologies/tourism#TESTIndRating -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://tourister.space/ontologies/tourism#TESTIndRating">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://tourister.space/ontologies/tourism#Rating"/>
        <hasStarRating xml:lang="string">5</hasStarRating>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Comment: We need more details. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why can't you use a simpler query and remove the inner curly braces? And I would suggest you to use some proper language tag for the language value and not `string`

Comment: The RDF is also incorrect.  `xml:lang="string"`??  I'd suggest not hand-writing RDF/XML.  It's simply not human readable.

Answer (score 0):

Many things unclear about the data and the query.  Here's an alternative in the more readable, and SPARQL-friendly, Turtle text serialization.  I also simplified the model, as it isn't clear that the `Rating` and `Feature` classes are needed (they could be, and can easily be added back in):

```
@prefix tourister: <http://example.org/ex#> .

tourister:TESTInd
   rdf:type tourister:Hotel ;
   tourister:hasFeature "Pool"^^xsd:string ;
   tourister:hasStarRating 5 .
tourister:Hotel
   rdf:type owl:Class ;
   rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing .
tourister:hasFeature
   rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
   rdfs:range xsd:string .
tourister:hasStarRating
   rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
   rdfs:range xsd:integer .
```

From this it seems that the SPARQL to find Hotels with a star rating of 5 and a Pool is taken almost directly from the first set of triples:

```
SELECT ?hotel
WHERE {
   ?hotel tourister:hasFeature "Pool"^^xsd:string ;
          tourister:hasStarRating 5 .
}
```

That's just a start, and I won't be the first to suggest doing a bit of homework on RDF and SPARQL before proceeding further.  I think you'll find that path more productive for getting started than piecemeal questions on SO.